# In Matlab, how can I sync audio with a plot?

Tags: matlab, audio, callback, playback, audio-player

I'm using `[y, Fs, nbits, opts] = wavread(filename)` to read in a wave file.  Next I `plot(t, y)` where `t = 0:1/Fs:(length(y)-1)/Fs`.  I play the wav via `sound(y, Fs)`.  My question is, is there a way to have a marker of some sort displayed in the plot that is synced with audio from the wav?  I am hoping to listen to the audio while observing where in the plot the corresponding sound is via a marker that moves within the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a solution with good synchronisation. This works well because the `audioplayer` object is initiating the callback that updates the play head location. Here is the calling script . . .

```
fs = 44100;
durT = 3; %seconds
durS = fs*durT; %samples
x = randn(durS, 1);

dt = 1/fs;
tAxis = dt:dt:durT;

frameRate = 25; %fps
frameT = 1/frameRate;

mag = 5;

figure;
plot(tAxis, x);
ylim([-mag mag])
xlim([0 durT])
xlabel('Time [s]')

playHeadLoc = 0;
hold on; ax = plot([playHeadLoc playHeadLoc], [-mag mag], 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);

player = audioplayer(x, fs);
myStruct.playHeadLoc = playHeadLoc;
myStruct.frameT = frameT;
myStruct.ax = ax;

set(player, 'UserData', myStruct);
set(player, 'TimerFcn', @apCallback);
set(player, 'TimerPeriod', frameT);
play(player);
```

...and here is the callback function that you can store in a separate file ...

```
function src = apCallback(src, eventdata)
    myStruct = get(src, 'UserData'); %//Unwrap

    newPlayHeadLoc = ...
        myStruct.playHeadLoc + ...
        myStruct.frameT;
    set(myStruct.ax, 'Xdata', [newPlayHeadLoc newPlayHeadLoc])

    myStruct.playHeadLoc = newPlayHeadLoc;
    set(src, 'UserData', myStruct); %//Rewrap
end
```

I have just made the signal a noise sample that you can replace with whatever you like. It is a shame that the `audioplayer` object has `stop` and `resume` methods without any access to a current play head location. Fortunately, there is a user data property that allows you to cram in whatever you like.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your help on this.  I should be able to try this out later and then report back my results.  I think this should be good enough for what I'm trying to do.  Have you tried running each one of those functions in their own thread?  Actually I'm not sure threading is available without an additional toolbox.

Comment: Even with the parallel processing toolbox, you will not have the granular control over threads that other general purpose languages will give you.

Comment: I've been trying out what you had posted, but I think I'm missing something.  The plot shows up with the random data in it, and the marker is sitting at the beginning, but it doesn't move after the call to play().  I imagine it's just that I'm missing something.  Thanks again.

Comment: The function `apCallback` should reside in a file called `apCallback.m` in the same folder as the script containing the other text pasted above. This is the most likely problem. I tested the code before posting.

Comment: That's how I have it setup, but it does look like the apCallback isn't getting called.  How do the arguments to apCallback get passed?

Comment: `src` and `eventdata` are passed automatically. I make the callback update `src` http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_plots/function-handle-callbacks.html

Comment: I copy and pasted the main part of the script into the command line, and it worked.  Not sure why putting it in its own .m file made a difference.

Comment: The main script should work from the command line or any file so long as apCallback is on the path. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Coming back to this, I am still unable to get the main code to run properly from a function.  If I copy and paste the code from the main function into the Matlab command line, it works fine.  But if I call the function from the command line, then for some reason it doesn't want to call apCallback.  Both m functions are in the MATLAB directory.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I think it has to do with the function returning immediately and not waiting for the player to play.  I put a pause() at the end of the function and it played some.

Comment: Try playblocking instead of play and see what happens